# Jquery prepend HTML to an Ajax created array

Tags: jquery, arrays, prepend

I am trying to prepend some HTML to an AJAX created table. Here is the code:

```
 success: function (msg) {
 var ang = '';
 var obj = $.parseJSON(msg);
 $.each(obj, function() {
    ang += '<table><tr><td width="165">' + this["Athlete_Name"] + '(' + this["Athlete_Number"] + ')</td><td width="55">'+ this["Scratch_Flag"] +'</td><td width="55">'+ this["Ready_Time"] +'</td><td width="55">'+ this["Flag_Time"] +'</td><td width="55">'+ this["End_Time"] +'</td><td width="55">'+ this["Score_Time"] +'</td></tr></table>';
                    });
                    $('<p>Roster</p>').prependTo('.html(ang)');
                    $('#' + ID ).hide().html(ang).fadeIn('fast');
            }
```

The Line of code called:

```
    $('<p>Roster</p>').prependTo('.html(ang)');
```

Is not appending to my array of HTML that is created called 'ang'
could someone point me in the right direction? many thanks

Comment: You're misusing `prependTo`. You should be using `yourelement.prepend(ang)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/)

If you try add ang to $('

Roster

') element, than you must write some code like this:

```
$(ang).prependTo('<p>Roster</p>');
```

But I really don't understand what that code means:

```
prependTo('.html(ang)')
```

Can you tell more info about .html command in target selector?

If you try to add `<p>Roster</p>` element before your table, just put `<p>Roster</p>` to ang declaration like:

```
var ang = '<p>Roster</p>';
```